# occur error while extending length of array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i have wrote a code but when i am trying to change the valuables, schedule(2,:) occurs error. my code:

```
clc;clear;
a = [1 2 3 4];
N = 3;
schedule(1,:) = kron(a,ones(1,N));% repeat 4 days
schedule(2,:) = repmat([1 2 3],1,4); % repeat time slots in each day %nums col rep
schedule(3,:) = randperm(12); % randomize 12 courses
schedule
```

is a way to match length of schedule(2,:) with others? for example when length  of other is 20, schedule(2,:) does not build more than 20. it's not standard.
thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change `day` and / or `repeat` the error occurs in

```
schedule(2,:) = repmat([1 2 3],1,4);
```

because the size of the `array` generated by `repmat([1 2 3],1,4)` has always the same length while the length of the arrays generated by using `kron` and `randperm` changes according to the definiton of `day` and `repeat`.

A possible solution could be to modify the instruction

`schedule(2,:) = repmat([1 2 3],1,4);`

as follows:

```
schedule(2,:) = repmat([1:repeat],1,length(day))
```

This solution allows `schedule(2,:)` having the same length of `schedule(1,:)` and `schedule(1,:)`.

Hope this helps.